# How to filter an array based on last name?

Tags: php

I have an array as follows:

```
Array(
    [0] => 'Sarah, Green',
    [1] => 'Adam, Brown',
    [2] => 'Fred, Able'
);
```

From this array I need to sort based on the last name.

I have tried following code:

```
$this->sortByLastName($data);


private function sortByLastName($data)
{
    $result = uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
        $splitFirstItem = explode(',', $a);
        $spliteSecondItem = explode(',', $b);

        $firstItemElement = trim(end($splitFirstItem));
        $secondItemElement = trim(end($spliteSecondItem));

        return strcasecmp($firstItemElement, $secondItemElement);
    });


    return $result;
}
```

But I am just getting true as the result.

What mistake I have done here.

Answer (score 1):

[`uasort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) simply returns `true`/`false` dependent on whether it completed successfully or not. The array is sorted in place, so your code should look like:

```
private function sortByLastName($data)
{
    uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
        $splitFirstItem = explode(',', $a);
        $spliteSecondItem = explode(',', $b);

        $firstItemElement = trim(end($splitFirstItem));
        $secondItemElement = trim(end($spliteSecondItem));

        return strcasecmp($firstItemElement, $secondItemElement);
    });


    return $data;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hJDUZ)

Answer (score 1):

Change your function as below.

```
private function sortByLastName($data)
{
    uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
        $splitFirstItem = explode(',', $a);
        $spliteSecondItem = explode(',', $b);

        $firstItemElement = trim(end($splitFirstItem));
        $secondItemElement = trim(end($spliteSecondItem));

        return strcasecmp($firstItemElement, $secondItemElement);
    });


    return $data;
}
```

This is because uasort does not return the array but changes the array passed to it. It only returns boolean true or false depending upon if the process was succesful